# How to place a DirectX object in a web page

Tags: html, plugins, directx

How do I place a DirectX object inside a plugin area?

I'm using FireBreath. The plugin is supposed to work on Firefox, IE, Chrome.

Thanks!

Sara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a browser plugin for all browser using firebreath.

The framework provide a HWND to the plugin window which 
I used to draw the DirectX easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access the DirectX api in Windows from a webbrowser. You can use WebGL but that's not supported by all browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, without creating a browser-specific extension to display DirectX objects.  DirectX is a closed technology owned by Microsoft and never likely to be implemented by open web standards due to lack of cross-platform compatibility and licensing issues.

Comment: OK. How do I do it through an extension?

Comment: @sara: the easiest approach would be to write an ActiveX control for Internet Explorer, since you can write them in .NET and .NET has built-in APIs for DirectX.  You'll need to be able to code in the .NET languages, though.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx is one tutorial.

Comment: I already have an ActiveX plugin written. How do I include the directX? what is the API to use?